# How to delete training definitions?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-studio

I am trying out Watson Studio visual modeler for neural networks.  During learning I have tried a few different designs and I have published several training definitions.

If I navigate to Experiment Builder, I see a lot of definitions some are old and no longer needed.

[image]

How can I delete old training definitions? (Ideally from the Watson Studio UI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Watson Machine Learning python client](https://datascience.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/ml_dlaas_environment_pyclient.html) doesn't support deleting training run definitions.  [WML's python client API](http://wml-api-pyclient-dev.mybluemix.net/) shows what options are supported. The WML team is working to add such delete functionality though.

In the meantime, you can use [WML's CLI tool](https://datascience.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/ml_dlaas_environment.html) to execute `bx ml delete`:

`NAME:
   delete - Delete a model/deployment/training-run/training-definitions/experiments/experiment-runs
USAGE:
   bx ml delete models MODEL-ID
   bx ml delete deployments MODEL-ID DEPLOYMENT-ID
   bx ml delete training-runs TRAINING-RUN-ID
   bx ml delete training-definitions TRAINING-DEFINITION-ID
   bx ml delete experiments EXPERIMENT-ID
   bx ml delete experiment-runs EXPERIMENT-ID EXPERIMENT-RUN-ID`

Use `bx ml list` to get details on the items that you wish to delete:

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the python client supports deleting training definitions.
You just call *client.repository.delete(artifact_uid)*. The same method can be used to delete any item from repository (model, training_definition, experiment). It is documented in python client docs btw:

delete(artifact_uid)

```
Delete model, definition or experiment from repository.
Parameters: artifact_uid ({str_type}) – stored model, definition, or experiment UID

A way you might use me is:

>>> client.repository.delete(artifact_uid)
```

Training_run is completely different thing than training_definition.
You can also remove it if needed:

delete(run_uid)

```
Delete training run.
Parameters: run_uid ({str_type}) – ID of trained model

A way you might use me is:

>>> client.training.delete(run_uid)
```

You can also remove the experiment_run if needed by calling:

delete(experiment_run_uid)

```
Delete experiment run.
Parameters: experiment_run_uid ({str_type}) – experiment run UID

A way you might use me is

>>> client.experiments.delete(experiment_run_uid)
```

Please refer to python client docs for more details: http://wml-api-pyclient-dev.mybluemix.net/